# json_encode is cutting off some characters

Tags: php, json

I have a simple array that I am creating in php from some mysql results.

An example of the data in the array is as follows from a var_dump of the array.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["value1a"]=>
    string(2) "26"
    ["value3a"]=>
    string(136) "Curriculum includes NCLEX prep work throughout all degree courses—preparing you to pass the NCLEX-RN exam and become a registered nurse."
    ["value3b"]=>
    string(223) "$150 course fee includes: textbooks, ebooks and CDs, three sets of scrubs, all lab fees, stethoscope, bandage scissors, pen light, and your NCLEX application fee"
    ["soc_code"]=>
    string(10) "29-1141.00"
    ["soc_title"]=>
    string(17) "Registered"
    ["job_growth"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["salary"]=>
    string(5) "65950"
    ["program_name"]=>
    string(20) "Professional"
  }
}
```

when I do a json_encode of the array such as `json_encode($results)` Everything works great but my value for value3a is cut off after 1 word.  The values for the rest are all what they should be including value3b which is long like value3a.

Here is example result when I echo `json_encode($results)`

`[{"value1a":"26","value3a":"Curriculum","value3b":"$150 course fee includes: textbooks, ebooks and CDs...etc`

Any help would be appreciated as I am not sure what is causing it.  I have tried to remove the first word from the value of value3a and then it still only list one word which is now the second word.

Here is what I am doing to see the data so I know the array is not being changed before encoding it.

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($results);
echo "</pre>";
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Are you sure the array isn't being modified before you do `json_encode`?

Comment: I am sure as that is the results of a var_dump on the $results array write before I do the echo json_encode($results)

Comment: Looks just like this    echo "<pre>";
var_dump($results);
echo "</pre>";
echo json_encode($results);

Comment: Where does the data come from? The space after "Curriculum" may be a non-standard space character, that's the only possible reason I can see

Comment: It is being pulled from a mysql database.  I will check the data to see but I know I have cut the data from the database and pasted it notepad and then put it back in the database field which I would assume would remove any odd characters in the spaces.

Comment: You are correct.  I just retyped it manually from the database and it worked just fine now.  Thanks as I didn't think it could be a bad space.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bad spacing character which was fixed thanks to a comment from Pekka.